# Unable to open PDF

Tags: pdf

I can't open a downloaded PDF file with Document Viewer. I get:

> Unable to open document “file:///home/myuser/myfile.pdf”.   File type
>   Perl script (application/x-perl) is not supported

The same file opens fine with Print Preview (GNOME Document Previewer) as well as on my son's Windows 7 box with Acrobat.

What's missing?

Comment: And how do you try to open it? It looks like file association is wrong. Did you try to right-click it and choose "Document Viewer"?

Comment: Yes I did that. I should have said that other PDF's open fine, so it is not the file associations. Thanks

Comment: can you share the pdf, or its location?

Comment: What does `file /home/myuser/myfile.pdf` say the file is? Are you sure it's a PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, the mentioned file is a perl application, despite being saved as pdf file.

Just to make sure what is the true type of your file, use the `file` command like this:

```
file /home/myuser/myfile.pdf
```

and make sure it is the result be something like this:

```
/home/myuser/myfile.pdf: PDF document, version x
```